# Python DataFrames Joining Integers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, integer

Hello just a quick question before i try something what can't work,

I want to produce DataFrames with only ints in it, positive and negative.

The question is if i join/merge them (or whatever) is it possible that the values in each row/column are added together ?

thanks for reading

Greetz

Comment: Can you please explain using sample input and expected output?

Comment: sample input is 0 literally 0 sample output would be a DataFrame with 1000 rows and 1000 columns and after that you have a second dataframe with indexes inside 1000x1000 and numbers in it like +1 and then i want to join dataFrame b with +1 to dataFrame a with 0 so after that dataFrame a holds a 1 in every cell dataFrame b had a +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The question is if i join/merge them (or whatever) is it possible that the values in each row/column are added together ?

Yes, that would be one of the most basic operations you can do with a pandas dataframe, you can simply add the two dataframes. Here's an example:

```
array1 = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
array2 = np.array([[1,1,1], [2,2,2]])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(array1, columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(array2, columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

print(df1+df2)
    col1  col2  col3
0     2     3     4
1     6     7     8
```

Comment: You mean simply adding two dataframes? `df1 + df2`?

Comment: thanks but not exactly what i wanted. I want to know if a can join a second dataFrame into yours like if i would have something 
{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}
and then join it with yours i would recieve
{2,3,4},{5,6,7}

Comment: if they are then added at their indexes yeah

Comment: Is that what you're asking for? Check edit @ChristophPelzer

Comment: exactly thank you. Now i just have to create a dataFrame with 1000*1000 0 in it ^^

Comment: Please don't forget to accept answer if it helped :-)